# Jupyter notebook kernel dies when creating dummy variables with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, azure-machine-learning-service

I am working on the Walmart Kaggle competition and I'm trying to create a dummy column of of the "FinelineNumber" column. For context, `df.shape` returns `(647054, 7)`. I am trying to make a dummy column for `df['FinelineNumber']`, which has 5,196 unique values. The results should be a dataframe of shape `(647054, 5196)`, which I then plan to `concat` to the original dataframe.

Nearly every time I run `fineline_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df['FinelineNumber'], prefix='fl')`, I get the following error message `The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.` I am running python 2.7 in jupyter notebook on a MacBookPro with 16GB RAM.

Can someone explain why this is happening (and why it happens most of the time but not every time)? Is it a jupyter notebook or pandas bug? Also, I thought it might have to do with not enough RAM but I get the same error on a Microsoft Azure Machine Learning notebook with >100 GB of RAM. On Azure ML, the kernel dies every time - almost immediately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It very much could be memory usage - a 647054, 5196 data frame has 3,362,092,584 elements, which would be 24GB just for the pointers to the objects on a 64-bit system.  On AzureML while the VM has a large amount of memory you're actually limited in how much memory you have available (currently 2GB, soon to be 4GB) - and when you hit the limit the kernel typically dies.  So it seems very likely it is a memory usage issue.

You might try doing [.to_sparse()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/sparse.html) on the data frame first before doing any additional manipulations.  That should allow Pandas to keep most of the data frame out of memory.