# jupyter notebook kernel dies when use mxnet ImageRecordIter with cifar10_val.rec

Tags: deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, mxnet

The cell is like below, trying to use `cifar10_val.rec`.The file is there.

```
def get_data_from_cifar(): 
    train = mx.io.ImageRecordIter() 
    val = mx.io.ImageRecordIter() 
    return train, val 

train, val = get_data_from_cifar()
```

Everytime I run the notebook it dies,telling

> The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

There is a post about [jupyter notebook kernel dies when using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34047782/1278112),it's about memory,however it has `to_sparse()` to deal with that.

The memory in my pc is not huge also.However,while running the cell,the taks manager doesn't show the memory like to be exhausted.

Could this be some other problem?

UPDATE:

run scripts in python interpreter shell it tells as @leezu said

> 304: [16:36:58] src/io/image_aug_default.cc:282: Check failed:
>   static_cast(res.rows) >= param_.data_shape[1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34047782/1278112) &&
>   static_cast(res.cols) >= param_.data_shape[2] input image
>   size smaller than input shape

guess I used wrong data_shape(3,128,128).Would update after change them acording to cifar10 instance.

Comment: What happens if you run this in a python script? I.e. paste the code to a file `script.py` and run `python script.py`.

Comment: Also how much RAM (in numbers) could be necessary.

Comment: may I ask you to mark the question as answered(ideally extracting the answer from the question to the stand alone answer)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out what cifar10 have is 60000 32*32 images.After change data_shape to (3,32,32) it doesn't die anymore.

Actually have to set the label_width to 1 also.
However the error can be track from the terminal.